# Create stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame like this:

```
df <- read.csv(text = "ONE,TWO,THREE
                       23,234,324
                       34,534,12
                       56,324,124
                       34,234,124
                       123,534,654")
```

I want to produce a percent bar plot which looks like this (made in LibreOffice Calc):
[image]

Thus, the bars should be standarized so all stacks have the same height and sums to 100%. So far all I have been able to get is is a stacked barplot (not percent), using:

```
barplot(as.matrix(df))
```

Any help?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Here's a solution using that `ggplot` package (version 3.x) in addition to what you've gotten so far.

We use the `position` argument of `geom_bar` set to `position = "fill"`. You may also use `position = position_fill()` if you want to use the arguments of `position_fill()` (`vjust` and `reverse`).

Note that your data is in a 'wide' format, whereas `ggplot2` requires it to be in a 'long' format. Thus, we first need to `gather` the data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- read.table(text = "    ONE TWO THREE
1   23  234 324
2   34  534 12
3   56  324 124
4   34  234 124
5   123 534 654",sep = "",header = TRUE)

# Add an id variable for the filled regions and reshape
datm <- dat %>% 
  mutate(ind = factor(row_number())) %>%  
  gather(variable, value, -ind)

ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
    # or:
    # geom_bar(position = position_fill(), stat = "identity") 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image: example figure]

Comment: what package is melt() part of? Is it reshape2?

Comment: Yes; my apologies. For such a long time ggplot2 loaded those packages on its own, I've grown rusty.

Comment: I tried it using melt from the reshape package and I got the following error: "Error in scale$labels(breaks) : unused argument(s) (breaks)" I wonder if it is because I am reading from a csv.

Comment: @JulioDiaz Hmmm. Hard to say what's going on, particularly if the data you're working with don't look exactly like the example in your question. I would make sure all packages are up to date, and that you're on R 2.14.2 (I had to upgrade to 2.14.2 to get some stuff in ggplot 0.9.0 to work).

Comment: I updated the way my data actually comes, which should not be different in any way other than sep=",". I also checked and R.version() 2.14.2 and ggplot2_0.9.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8551/discussion-between-julio-diaz-and-joran)

Comment: I restarted R and it worked. I don't know what restarting did.

Comment: When I try to use this method, I get the following error: `Error: Labels can only be specified in conjunction with breaks` which has to do with the `labels = percent_format()` call.  Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: @KLee1 Check your version of ggplot2. Note that my answer refers specifically to version 0.9.0 (or later).

Comment: @joran Thanks.  It turned out that I needed to set the formatter parameter in my version to see the same effect in case anyone reads this in the future.

Comment: @Henk Thanks for the correction. Your edit was rejected by people who didn't know R enough to know that you're right. Until you have the ability to edit Q's yourself, you should expect edit reviews to be fairly "cautious" in this regard.

Comment: For those coming to this after 2018, replace 

            "labels = percent_format()" with "scales::percent".

Comment: @stuartstevenson it doesn't appear so simple, please elaborate and edit the answer

Comment: @stuartstevenson This should not be required. `scales` is imported automatically, you just have to prefix the function and use `scales::percent_format()`.

Comment: What if we have no variables, just one bar that we want to colour by proportions?

Comment: @joran Hi. can you say how to do this data manipulation without dplyr?

Answer (score 20):

Chris Beeley is rigth, you only need the proportions by column. Using your data is:

```
 your_matrix<-( 
               rbind(
                       c(23,234,324), 
                       c(34,534,12), 
                       c(56,324,124), 
                       c(34,234,124),
                       c(123,534,654)
                    )
                )

 barplot(prop.table(your_matrix, 2) )
```

## Gives:

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Really simple and simply works.

Comment: @kboom it doesn't use `ggplot2` whereby the OP tagged his question

Answer (score 14):

prop.table is a nice friendly way of obtaining proportions of tables.

```
m <- matrix(1:4,2)

 m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Leaving margin blank gives you proportions of the whole table

```
 prop.table(m, margin=NULL)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.1  0.3
[2,]  0.2  0.4
```

Giving it 1 gives you row proportions

```
 prop.table(m, 1)
      [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.2500000 0.7500000
[2,] 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

And 2 is column proportions

```
 prop.table(m, 2)
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.4285714
[2,] 0.6666667 0.5714286
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to divide each element by the sum of the values in its column.

Doing this should suffice:

```
data.perc <- apply(data, 2, function(x){x/sum(x)})
```

Note that the second parameter tells `apply` to apply the provided function to columns (using 1 you would apply it to rows). The anonymous function, then, gets passed each data column, one at a time.

Comment: Hello, this didn't quiet adjusted my data, `rowSums(data.perc)` wasn't 1 for each line. Instead I used this: `data.perc <- apply(data, 2, function(x){x/(apply(data,1,sum))})`

Comment: did you have NAs or zero-summing lines? Otherwise I don't quite understand why that wouldn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the [scalesextra](https://github.com/thomas-neitmann/scalesextra) package with [scale_y_pct](https://rdrr.io/github/emilelatour/laviz/src/R/scale_pct.R) function which is able to create a percentage scale directly from your data. First, transform the data to a longer format using `pivot_longer` and create a percentage column per group. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# remotes::install_github("thomas-neitmann/scalesextra")
library(scalesextra)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(index = factor(row_number()),
         pct = value/sum(value)*100) %>% # Create percentage values
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(name, levels = unique(name)), y = pct, fill = index)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_pct() +
  labs(x = "Name")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For some extra info about this package and function check this [tutorial](https://thomasadventure.blog/posts/ggplot2-percentage-scale/).