# R plot for showing true/false positives

Tags: r, plot

I'm looking for a way to plot my data.  Suppose you have a number of algorithms that produce a ranked list, and a classifier that identifies each item in the list as true or false.  How can I produce a chart that puts each algorithm beside each other and each rank has its own square stacked as follow:

```
      __   __
 3   |TP| |FP|
     |__| |__|
 2   |FP| |TP|
     |__| |__|
 1   |TP| |TP|
     |__| |__|
      a    b
```

Where TP could be coloured green and FP could be coloured red for example.

Comment: Maybe a mosiac plot [(LINK)](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/mosaic.html)

Comment: Hi @Robert, you may want to check if the solutions solve your issue and accept the best one

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ggplot2` for drawing a [stacked barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-percent-barplot-in-r). However a better way to compare the true/false positive/negatives of algorithms is [precision/recall (same as selectivity/specificity)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rocplus/vignettes/rocplus.pdf) chart.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done very easily with base R, using the `heatmap()` function.

Try this:

```
# Dataframe with TRUE/FALSE items
mydf <- data.frame(a = c(T, F, T), b = c(T, T,F))

# Transform booleans into 1s and 0s, and plot heatmap
heatmap(apply(mydf, 2, as.integer),
        col = c("red", "lightgreen"),
        xlab = "Algorithm", 
        ylab = "Item", 
        main = "False positives in red", 
        Rowv = NA, 
        Colv = NA,
        scale = "column")
```

[image: True/False heatmap plot generated with R]