# Plotting binary variable as percentage

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset with two variables: 1) Country; 2) Coalition government or not over time (binary).

I want to use ggplot to plot a bar plot in which I have country on the X-axis and the percentage of years in which the country had a coalition government (Y=1). Each of the countries should sum to 100 pct. leading to them having the same size.

It is basically the same plot which is asked for in this question ([Create stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-percent-barplot-in-r)), except that I have only two outcomes (coalition government or not) and not five.

Although I follow the instructions in the answer to the question, I get the attached unsuccesful plot, using this code:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = countryname, y = alliance,fill = alliance)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = percent_format())
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I have tried so many different things now. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The problem is in your data frame.  Re-read the original answer and look more carefully at the solution.  Note it used "y=value" (the value column created by the melt), not "y=ind".

Comment: Thank you. I changed a few things according to the link. But now I get the following error:

"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (29160): x, y, fill"

The code I used is: 

dat.m <- melt(data,id.vars = "countryname")
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = countryname, y = value,fill=alliance)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')

"Alliance" is a binary variable (0 or 1 depending on whether the country in the given year formed a coalition government or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and answer by generating some random data to match your description. Hopefully you can re-purpose this example for your needs.

```
# Sample data set
year <- 1990:2016

n <- length(year)
country <- rep(c("US", "Canada", "England", "France", "Germany"), each = n)
govt <- sample(c(1, 0), size = length(country), replace = T)

df <- data.frame(country, year = rep(year, times = 5), govt)
head(df)

# Create summary
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df.plot <- df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarize(coalition = sum(govt)/n(),
            non.coalition = 1-coalition)

# Check
rowSums(df.plot[,-1])

# Now plot
df.plot %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = country, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  xlab("Country") + 
  ylab("Percent Coalition / Non Coalition") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Type of Govt."))
```