# how to make a bar plot for character value with percent format by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to make a bar plot with percent format.
here is my data set:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xpRqQwzKFuirpKYKcoi1qVYSaiA-D5WX/view?usp=sharing

```
load('test.Robj')
```

Here is my part of data looks like:

```
                     res.1.2 branch
AAACCTGCACCAGGCT       0      1
AAACCTGGTCATATGC       7      4
AAACCTGGTTAGTGGG      15     NA
AAACCTGTCCACGCAG       1     NA
AAACCTGTCCACGTTC      17      2
AAACGGGCACCGAATT       0      1
```

I tried to use this code to plot:

```
ggplot(test,aes(x = branch, y =factor(1),fill = res.1.2)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity")+
  scale_y_discrete(labels =scales::percent)
```

I want to make my y axis as percent of counts of res.1.2 in total(stacked bar chart, or similar to a pie chart), 
quite similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100)
but I got this:
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)

Comment: I tried scale_y_continuous or scale_y_discrete, but it seems not to be working on character format.

Comment: This: `y =factor(1)` looks suspicious. (The graph doesn't look like what I would expect from that data so I'm not making any efforts at coding.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the result of `dput(test)`. Without, it will be difficult to track down the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe, you are amazing! why did you delete your post? it works for me ! Really appreciate your help! It seems as.integer(res.1.2) helps, can you explain that a little?

Comment: @MichaelXu I deleted my post because I was not sure if I had understood your question correctly. Now, I have undeleted my answer and have added an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to plot the values of `res.1.2` which are of type `character`. So, `res.1.2` needs to be coerced to integer for plotting:

```
# load OP's data
load('test.Robj')
# create plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test,aes(x = branch, y = as.integer(res.1.2), fill = res.1.2)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

However, if the OP intends to show the number of occurrences of each value of `res.1.2` as share of total within each `branch`, the code is as follows:

```
# load OP's data
load('test.Robj')
# create plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(x = branch, fill = res.1.2)) +  
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

The chart shows the counts of `res.1.2` as percentage for each `branch`

Comment: really detailed and thorough, you are right ,I am using the 'occurrences ' rather than 'value'!