# Stacked barplot with percentage in R ggplot2 for categorical variables from scratch

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've installed `ggplot2` 3.1.0 on my PC. My raw data look like (short example of the long data frame):

```
structure(list(genotype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
    type = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R")), row.names = c(NA, 
19L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the code to obtain the following plot :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_test,aes(x=factor(genotype),fill=factor(type)))+geom_bar(stat="count")+xlab("Genotype")
```

[image]

But now i need to substitute the count by percentage, to show that 100% of the observations with genotype have type M and the same for genotype C (100% observations belong to type R). I tried to follow the post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100)

My code was:

```
ggplot(df,aes(type,x=genotype,fill=type)+geom_bar(stat="identity")+xlab("Genotype")+scales::percent)
```

But got the error:
Error in aes(y = type, x = genotype, fill = type) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Could you please help me to fix the error?

Comment: Use `dput` to add sample data not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I used solution provided by NelsonGon, but maked it a bit shorter. Besides i always try to avoid of using third party libraries if it's possible. So the code working for me was:

```
ggplot(df_test,aes(x=factor(genotype),fill=factor(type)))+geom_bar(position="fill")+xlab("Genotype")+scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent_format())
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this it?

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(type=c(rep("A",5),rep("C",5)),genotype=c(rep("M",5),rep("R",5)))

    df %>% 
      mutate_if(is.character,as.factor) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(genotype,fill=type))+geom_bar(position="fill")+
      theme_minimal()+
      scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent_format())
```