# Error: Change color in a stacked bar plor ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color in a stacked barplot using `ggplot2`. I searched for a while on the internet and I have found some suggestions, but they didn't work.

I tried:

`scale_fill_grey(start=0.5, end=0)`

and

`scale_color_gradient(11="dark", 22="grey")`

and

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
```

They are all not working. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance.

```
dput(IC)
structure(list(station = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), morning = c(11L, 
22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 22L, 
11L, 22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 22L), number = c(52L, 48L, 38L, 48L, 
68L, 32L, 144L, 63L, 125L, 40L, 37L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 18L, 6L, 13L, 
35L, 39L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L
))
```

Comment: This is my script: options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input <- "C:\\Users\\IC.csv"
IC <- read.csv(input, sep=";")
dput(IC)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

plot<- ggplot(IC,aes(x=station, y=number, fill=morning)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.5, end=0)

print(plot)

Comment: Check to see if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change to the y-axis to percent format, use the `scales` package. I've given an answer on the same here: [Stacked barplot with percentage in R ggplot2 for categorical variables from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236730/stacked-barplot-with-percentage-in-r-ggplot2-for-categorical-variables-from-scra/54236934#54236934)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
 IC %>% 
  mutate(morning=as.factor(morning),number=as.numeric(number)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(station,number,fill=morning))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "fill")+
 scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent_format(),breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(n=10))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. It gives me the error: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: Could you show me the code you've used? Ensure to call `library(tidyverse)` and copy and paste this code. Don't add IC in `ggplot(aes(...))`

Comment: I wrote: library(tidyverse)

IC %>% 
  mutate(morning=as.factor(morning)) %>% 
 plot<- ggplot(IC,aes(x=station,y=number,fill=morning))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "fill")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
print(plot) It gives me the error:   could not find function "%>%<-"
But I have installed the package tidyverse.

Comment: Copy and paste the code in the answer without any modification first! **You cannot do this `%>% plot<-` **

Comment: I am sorry. I had a typing error. Now it is working with your code: ICI_morning %>% 
  mutate(morning=as.factor(morning)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=station,y=number,fill=morning))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "fill")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: I am sorry. I have one more question: I can't change the y-axis anymore. The graph in R has the y-axis label: 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00. But in my Excel sheet it is in %, e.g. 25, 50, 75, 100. How can I change this in R. When I try scale_y_continous(limits=c(0,100), breaks=seq(0,100,10)), it is not working.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I have the % at the axis, but I can't change the scale. I would like to have the axis in intervals of ten. And this is not working:  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100), breaks=seq(0,100,10),labels=scales::percent_format())

Comment: Thank you so much. It's perfect.