# How to make a stacking bar using ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2, graph, charts, ggplotly

[image]

I have got this dataset. I am trying to do a stacking bar graph with proportions using ggplot for this data:

[image]

I am not really sure how to manipulate it into tables first! I know, I just started learning R, two weeks ago and I'm kind of stuck. I made a similar graph before. I attached it here.

Comment: Hi, @AAAA. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include some example code so that we can see what you've tried and help correct any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but I'll try to answer it. I see that this is your first question in Stack Overflow, so I'd advise you to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on your next question.

#### 1) "I am not really sure how to manipulate it into tables first!"

Copy the data into an excel file, save it as csv and import into R with base R command.

```
df <- read.csv('your_data.csv')
```

#### 2) " do a stacking bar graph with proportions"

Your problem is very similar to the one mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100). Make sure to check it out, but I've already adapted the code below, see if it works.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)

    df <- read.csv('your_data.csv')

    # Add an id variable for the filled regions and reshape
    dfm <- df %>% 
      mutate(Domain = factor(row_number()) %>% 
      gather(variable, value, -Domain)

    ggplot(dfm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Domain)) + 
        geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
        # or:
        # geom_bar(position = position_fill(), stat = "identity"
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```