# stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100% + geom_text(), ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-bar, geom-text

I would like to extend the question posted here:
[Create stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100/9570321#9570321), of a scattered barplot with an argument of `geom_bar` set to `position = "fill"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- read.table(text = "    ONE TWO THREE
1   23  234 324
2   34  534 12
3   56  324 124
4   34  234 124
5   123 534 654",sep = "",header = TRUE)

# Add an id variable for the filled regions and reshape
datm <- dat %>% 
  mutate(ind = factor(row_number())) %>%  
  gather(variable, value, -ind)

ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
    # or:
    # geom_bar(position = position_fill(), stat = "identity") 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image: example figure]

Imagine you would like to add segment labels. It works for me if I leave out `position = "fill",` (even though it messes up the y-axis scale).

```
ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    # or:
    # geom_bar(position = position_fill(), stat = "identity") 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
    geom_text(label= 'bla')
```

but, if I add `position = "fill",` the plot is messed up. The bars disappear as they are marginalized to for scale of up to 100, and the labels appear detached from bars in the grey area.

```
ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
    # or:
    # geom_bar(position = position_fill(), stat = "identity") 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
    geom_text(label= 'bla')
```

[image]

Why? How to? Thx!

Comment: Are you looking for `geom_text(label = "bla", position ="fill")`? Possibly `geom_text(label = "bla", position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))` for nicer text?

Comment: Ohh yes!!! That did it! Thax a lot!

Comment: @teunbrand would you care making this an answer so it could be accepted ?

Comment: Alright, if I must. Suggesting 1 line fixes in the comments is so much more convenient for me though :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to apply the fill position adjustment on the text layer too. You can control where the text will appear relative to the bounds by adjusting the `vjust` parameter.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

dat <- structure(list(ONE = c(23L, 34L, 56L, 34L, 123L), 
                      TWO = c(234L, 534L, 324L, 234L, 534L), 
                      THREE = c(324L, 12L, 124L, 124L, 654L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

# Add an id variable for the filled regions and reshape
datm <- dat %>% 
  mutate(ind = factor(row_number())) %>%  
  gather(variable, value, -ind)

ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  geom_text(label= 'bla', position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm only registering this as an answer so people browsing for unanswered questions don't stumble upon this one. It is way less effort for me to suggest a 1 line fix in the comments.